# Move_base error: Local costmap doesn't work (robot unable to do obstacle avoidance)

Tags: navigation, laser, ros-hydro, costmap, base-laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I am using Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.
I have tried the turtlebot_simulation tutorials and all went well.
I am using Kobuki robot but I have changed the laser scanner input from the kinect to a laser.
The laser seems to be correct as I can see the laser in RVIZ.
However, when I launch move_base, the local costmap does not seem to be reading the laser and hence the robot fails to avoid obstacles that are not on the map.
The global costmap shows correctly, but there is no local costmap.
I am using 100% the same settings as in turtlebot_navigation package - the only difference is that I have a laser model instead of the Kinect.

I have tried the following reference, but it still does not work.

http://answers.ros.org/question/128496/navigation-stack-cant-avoid-obstacles-in-hydro/

Any ideas? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202088/move_base-error:-local-costmap-doesn%27t-work-(robot-unable-to-do-obstacle-avoidance)/) by [jwang](https://answers.ros.org/users/21529/jwang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2015-01-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-01-30**:
Are you able to visualize the local costmap in Rviz?

**Comment by [jwang](https://answers.ros.org/users/21529/jwang/) on 2015-01-30**:
There is no local costmap in Rviz, only global costmap can been seen.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-01-30**:
Change the local_costmap update_frequency parameter to 1.0 and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out that after I change the min_obstacle_height of the laser from 0.25 to 0.0 in costmap_commom_params.yaml, the obstacles can be shown in the costmap now. And the robot can do obstacle avoidance. Still thank you for your reply!

---

Originally posted by [jwang](https://answers.ros.org/users/21529/jwang/) with karma: 56 on 2015-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3